# splice method error - object immutable - React Native app

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, splice

I have a list of items in my React Native App.

Initially the **item's "id"** is stored in an array of objects.

[image]

Each time i click an item the item's id is removed form the array.
Code for id removal:

```
      let found = this.state.genList.find((a) => a.id === item.id);
      let index = this.state.genList.indexOf(found);
      if (index > -1) {
        this.state.genList.splice(index, 1);
      }
      AsyncStorage.setItem('general_messages', this.state.genList);
```

Using splice I remove an element with the help of it's index.
This works only ONCE.
The next time I click an item I get the below error.

[image]

Why is "**splice**" causing this issue??
How else could I have written this??
Please help!!

Comment: splice mutates the array as mentioned in the error message

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice for details.

--> Return value:

    An array containing the deleted elements.
    
    If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned.
    
    If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.